# Return File not forcing download of file in .NET core API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core API trying to return a file for the browser to download when triggered.

```
[HttpGet("DownloadFile/{fileId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFile(string fileId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var file = await _fileUploadService.DownloadFile(Guid.Parse(fileId), _ambientState.UserId);

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

    var path = Path.Combine(
                   Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                   "fileuploads", file.FilePath);

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "event-doc" + Path.GetExtension(path));
}
```

But this doesn't force the download of the file I have tried many things but nothing causes the file to be downloaded by the browser. There are no errors either. The call to the API succeeds but no file is downloaded

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check in debug that your file is not empty? You could probably share more details on what "no file is downloaded" mean: you get 204, 200 with 0 bytes, wrong headers, etc.?

Comment: As I know, it is internet browser specific. Try changing the mime type by user-agent.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik The request returns 200 and the preview on devtools on chrome actually shows the image, but the image is not downloaded by the browser

Comment: What do you mean "not downloaded", it apparently was downloaded since you can see it. You probably mean the browser did not "download it as a file attachment" or did not show on screen, I suppose you want to download it as an attachment?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik The browser did not download it as a file attachment yes and i want it downloaded as an attachment

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a content-disposition header before you return the action result.

```cs
var header = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = document.FileName
};

Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, header.ToString());
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't make a difference

Comment: check filename as well, try first with a hardcoded "test", there are som tricks with UTF chars, etc.

Comment: Tried this by harcoding the filename and without, didn't work either way

Comment: Do you see that the header is present in the response from the server? Can you try in another browser as well?

Comment: Can you check that header is being returned in the response correctly in the browser?

Comment: Perhaps File response is overriding the header set directly to Response object

Comment: @KevinSmith  I have added images of what the header being returned looks like